# How to pick data from list in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

In PostgreSQL I am able to pick data from the query of a table. As for example I want to display entityname from t1  using for loop.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   e varchar;
BEGIN
   FOR e IN (SELECT entityname 
              FROM t1)
  LOOP

 raise notice 'Value: %', e;

END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

But If I already have list of entityname and I just want to display it. What will be the correct way, I tried using

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   e varchar;
BEGIN
  FOR e IN ('t1','t2')
  LOOP

 raise notice 'Value: %', e;

END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

But it is giving error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'t1'"
LINE 6:   FOR e IN ('t1','t2')
```

What will be the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct statement is [FOREACH target IN ARRAY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY), which iterates over a array:

```
FOREACH target [ SLICE number ] IN ARRAY expression LOOP
    statements
END LOOP;
```

Also in you case:

```
DO $do$ DECLARE e varchar;
BEGIN
  FOREACH e IN ARRAY ARRAY['t1','t2'] LOOP    
    raise notice 'Value: %', e;    
  END LOOP;
END $do$;
```